# How to implement a band-pass filter in WatchKit?

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, apple-watch

AppleWatch acceleration sensor (`CMSensorRecorder` 50Hz) is used for sleep measurement.

I don't know how to write a band-pass filter (2-3Hz) that filters the necessary data from sensor raw values. Is a bandpass filter a combination of a `lowpass` filter and a `highpass` filter?

I also don't know the exact scaling factor.

So could someone post some generic code for a band-pass Filter?

`lowpass` and `highpass` filter

```
func highpassFilter(acceleration: CMAcceleration){

        acceleX = Alpha * acceleration.x + acceleX * (1.0 - Alpha);
        acceleY = Alpha * acceleration.y + acceleY * (1.0 - Alpha);
        acceleZ = Alpha * acceleration.z + acceleZ * (1.0 - Alpha);

        let xh = acceleration.x - acceleX
        let yh = acceleration.y - acceleY
        let zh = acceleration.z - acceleZ

        accelerometerX.text = String(format: "%06f", xh)
        accelerometerY.text = String(format: "%06f", yh)
        accelerometerZ.text = String(format: "%06f", zh)
    }
```

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. Without showing at least some (research) effort you're highly unlikely to receive an answer. Research bandpass filters and their implementation in Swift, then once you have a more specific question, you're more probable to receive an answer. Your current question will likely be closed as too broad.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.I will write the progress.